# Get the object of abstract class in another class

Tags: java

I have a an abstract class Controller that extends `Mainpage`.Also i cant do any changes in the `MainPage`.Its not editable

```
public abstract class Controller extends MainPage {  
    public Controller(Remote remor) throws UnsuppoOSException, PException {     
           super(remor);           

    }
    }
```

MainPage class

```
public abstract class MainPage implements IPageObject {
    public Remote mDriver;
    public MainPage(Remote driver) throws PException {
        if (driver == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Cannot initialize with null driver");
        this.mDriver = driver;      
    }
}
```

What i need is to get the object of Controller and use in another class FactoryIndo

For that i extended the Controller class.

```
public abstract class FactoryIndo extends Controller {
    public static Remote mDriver;

    public FactoryIndo(Remote remor) throws UnsuppoOSException, PException {
        super(remor);
        mDriver = remor;
    }

public List<TestContext> getBrowserTestContext(List<String> browsers)
        throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> browserMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    browserMap.put(MasterConstants.BROWSER, this); // HERE am passing the object of Controller
    TestContext testContext = new TestContext(browser, browserMap);
    return testContext;
}

    public static List<TestContext> getTestContext(List<String> browsers)
            throws Exception {
        FactoryIndo instanceSel = new FactoryIndo(mDriver);
        List<TestContext> contexts = instanceSel
                .getBrowserTestContext(browsers);
        return contexts;
    }
}
```

While calling this getTestContext method in another class am getting Cannot initialize with null driver.
Whats wrong with my code.
Also without extending the Controller class is ther any possible way to get the object of this in  FactoryIndo class

Comment: That's because getTestContext is static and when it is being initialised mDriver is null.

Comment: Controller class is an abstract class and it can not be instantiated, rather than Instance creation there can be an  instantiation anonymous subclass of Controller like this :
Controller control = new Controller() {}; in your FactoryIndo class.

Comment: i cant do like that..coz in parent mainclass there is no such constructor..

Answer (score 1):

That's because getTestContext is static and when it is being initialised mDriver is null.
You have to first assign a value to mDriver before you call

```
FactoryIndo instanceSel = new FactoryIndo(mDriver);
```

EDIT: Something like this

```
public static List<TestContext> getTestContext(List<String> browsers)
        throws Exception {
    mDriver = //Your code goes here
    FactoryIndo instanceSel = new FactoryIndo(mDriver);
    List<TestContext> contexts = instanceSel
            .getBrowserTestContext(browsers);
    return contexts;
}
```

Comment: how can i assign values to mDriver.where i can assign?

Comment: also any other ways to get the object of Controller class in FactoryIndo

Comment: Controller is an abstract class.You cannot create an instance of it directly. You need to first extend Controller and then you can create an instance of the class which extends Controller.
Also, I see too many abstract classes.Is it by design?

Comment: one doubt also can i declare mDriver inside of the constuctor public FactoryIndo(Remote remor) throws UnsuppoOSException, PException {
  super(remor);
  mDriver = remor;
 }

Comment: Yes you can and you can pass the same driver in the super call as well.

Comment: u mean  public FactoryIndo(Remote remor) throws UnsuppoOSException, PException { super(remor); mDriver = remor;  } i alreday tried that wat...but getting same error